# Customize DCA plot labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, vegan

I have a DCA object

```
summary(dca)

Site scores:

            DCA1      DCA2      DCA3      DCA4 Totals
AH_T1  -0.083971 -0.600384  0.513428  0.794499     18
AH_T2  -0.017126 -0.410023 -0.194760  0.282255     14
AH_T3  -0.079178 -0.244031  0.274927  0.570446     16
SB_T1  -0.413546  0.033417  0.762520  0.454288     17
HZ_T1  -0.205265 -0.401048 -0.329853  0.098905     20
HZ_T2  -0.051373 -0.707477 -0.626761 -0.090690     11
HZ_T3  -0.209482 -0.284500 -0.456123  0.287953     17
IH_T1  -0.017786  0.212286  0.402395 -0.408806     18
IH_T2  -0.394654 -0.129818  0.358900 -0.429682     15
IH_T3   0.059865 -0.261604  0.568370 -0.300224     16
IH_T4  -0.159250 -0.144365  0.498412 -0.599404     12
IH_T5  -0.547112 -0.189500  0.758668 -0.303647     20
IH_T6  -0.673832 -0.467925  0.924921 -0.210702     17
OST_T1 -0.080579 -0.168180 -0.074228 -0.395828     14
RW_T1  -0.347305 -0.005233 -0.492337 -0.074018     18
RW_T2  -0.430563 -0.081961 -0.039556 -0.289489     11
RW_T3  -0.427977 -0.401413 -0.733190  0.092576     20
RW_T4  -0.437579  0.115553 -0.466525 -0.155855     13
RW_T5  -0.497717 -0.057785 -0.089060 -0.257333     13
RWB_T1  0.992864 -0.084741 -0.172626  0.254606     22
RWB_T2  0.492169 -0.203401 -0.506953  0.511755     19
RWB_T3  1.372265  0.336062  0.070865  0.019864     16
RWB_T4  0.789543  0.168187  0.703618 -0.672646     17
WM_T1  -0.112521 -0.797035 -0.372285  0.077007     14
WM_T2   0.008648 -0.546527 -0.272787 -0.099172     15
WM_T3  -0.161854 -0.781419 -0.499302 -0.475927     18
WM_T4  -0.247226 -0.792233 -0.167708 -0.112969     12
WM_T5  -0.474015 -0.822478 -0.194942 -0.321107     11
WR_T3  -0.186818  0.314175 -0.157542 -0.245089      4
WR_T4  -0.421249  0.283086  0.021062  0.081024      9
FS_T1  -0.303028  2.147182 -0.215759  0.372133     13
FS_T2  -0.450260  1.934448 -0.277489 -0.023677      7
FS_T3  -0.342402  1.536942 -0.385465  0.105576      9
FS_T4  -0.770140  1.360177 -0.163095  0.172052     11
WR_T1  -1.268393  1.374820 -0.000533  0.180091     12
WR_T2  -1.099601  0.896554  0.059584  0.372984     16
RWB_Si  4.133449  0.575623  0.163993  0.115948     20
```

When I try to plot the object with the base plot function, there is a lack of customization.

```
plot (dca, display = 'sites', type = 'p', 
      main = "DCA", 
      cols = c("black"), pch = 3, cex = 0.7)

text(dca, display = 'sites', cex=0.7, pos=2)
```

[image]

The plot labels overlap, is there a way to sort out this issue?

I have tried to extract the data with a function I found to a similiar issue:

```
ggvegan_data <- function(object, axes = c(1, 2), layers = c("species", "sites"), ...){
  obj <- fortify(object, axes = axes, ...)
  obj <- obj[obj$Score %in% layers, , drop = FALSE]
  want <- obj$Score %in% c("species", "sites")
  obj[want, , drop = FALSE]
}
```

and then try to use ggplot

```
lichen.plot.data = ggvegan_data(dca)
p <- ggplot(data = plot.data, aes(x = DCA1, DCA2, colour = Score)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Label), nudge_y = 0.3)
p
```

But there is following error message:

```
Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class <decorana>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Could you share `dput(head(dca))` ? It should be a dataframe if you want to use it in your function

Comment: I have added the output of dput(head(dca))

Comment: have you tried **vegan** function `scores` with argument `tidy = TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found kind of a work around.

```
t2<-scores(dca)

#transorm it into a dataframe
t2<-as.data.frame(t2)

class(t2)

site.label <- c("AH_T1","AH_T2","AH_T3","SB_T1", "HZ_T1", "HZ_T2", "HZ_T3", "IH_T1","IH_T2","IH_T3","IH_T4","IH_T5","IH_T6","OST_T1","RW_T1 ",
                "RW_T2","RW_T3","RW_T4","RW_T5","RWB_T1","RWB_T2","RWB_T3","RWB_T4","WM_T1 ","WM_T2","WM_T3","WM_T4","WM_T5","WR_T3","WR_T4",
                "FS_T1","FS_T2","FS_T3","FS_T4","WR_T1","WR_T2","RWB_Si")
  
t2$label <- site.label 


#plot the data with ggplot
ggplot(data = t2, aes(x = DCA1, y = DCA2)) + theme_bw() + 
  
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label), 
                  box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines")) +
  
  geom_point(colour = "green", size = 3)
```

This gives me the ability to use data with ggplot and do different stuff with the label problem.

[image]